# Add email addresses to AD security groups using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to run the powershell script below, but I get:

*"Set-ADGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'mail'.*

***Script imports a two column csv (left column is group & right column is email address) and then loops through the list setting the mail attribute of each object in the list***

```
Import-CSV -path 'D:\Scripts\AD-AddEmailtoSecGroups\Groups&Emails_Test.csv' | ForEach {get-adgroup -id $_.group | set-adgroup -mail $_.Mail}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-Replace` parameter to access the mail property as it doesn't have its own parameter in `Set-ADGroup`. When passing the hash to the `-Replace` parameter, you also just need to make sure you're accessing the 'mail' property in your object you're passing over to the command appropriately.

This should do the trick:

```
Import-CSV -path 'D:\Scripts\AD-AddEmailtoSecGroups\Groups&Emails_Test.csv' |
ForEach-Object {Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.group -Replace @{mail="$($_.mail)"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Import-CSV -path 'D:\Scripts\AD-AddEmailtoSecGroups\Groups&Emails_Test.csv' | ForEach-Object {Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.group -Replace @{mail="$_.email"}}
```

**EDIT:**
I think I assumed the email property would be called 'email' in your csv. I just see that you are using 'mail' instead. So minor change:

```
Import-CSV -path 'D:\Scripts\AD-AddEmailtoSecGroups\Groups&Emails_Test.csv' | ForEach-Object {Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.group -Replace @{mail="$($_.mail)"}}
```

Comment: It populated the mail field for each security group, but this is what it put in the field:         **@{Group=secgroupname; Mail=secgroupname@domain.com}.email**

Comment: I want it to put the email address in the mail field.